# Launch process from Anaconda yml file

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml

Is it feasible to specify a start program/process in the .yml file. For example in jupyter notebook i would specify something like `!tabpy` to manually start the process. How do we specify this in the .yml file?

```
name: test-env
dependencies:
- python>=3.5
- anaconda
- pip
- numpy=1.13.3  
- pip:
  - docx
  - gooey
  - matplotlib==2.0.0
  - **!tabpy** -- can we do this ??
```

Comment: This is hugely unsafe to include as a feature. I doubt it exists. I certainly hope it doesn’t.

Comment: any idea how we cater such requirements

Comment: I do have similar Req where we need to operate our kubernetes cluster on a mixed mode (I.e) few nodes on stateless deployments  and other statefulsets.   Any thoughts how this can be achieved.